# How do I reset NE555 output to LOW when powered on?

Tags: 555

Here is a functional NE555 push-on push-off switch. But the problem with this is whenever the power source is connected, it starts in random On or Off position.

How to modify it so that it always remains in OFF position when power is just connected (aka. system is restarted).

For actual values, you can see a [YouTube video](https://youtu.be/yvj0nSbc23A?t=26).

[image: Fritzing drawing available]

Answer (score 3):

Pull up the reset to VCC with a resistor, and place a capacitor between the reset and ground, as show in the schematics.

When you power on the 555, C<sub>1</sub> will hold the /RESET line for a brief time. This will reset the flip-flop of the 555.

**NOTE:**
The reset input current on the TTL version of the 555 is very high (between 0.4 mA and 1.5 mA) so R must be rather small. 100 Ohm will ensure that the levels are within specifications.

Adjust the \$R_1 \cdot C_1\$ time constant so that the low-level pulse is longer than your power supply turn-on time.

EDIT: The diode allows quick discharging the capacitor in case there is a **very** quick turn off/on cycle (thanks @Brian Drummond).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqItdh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: And if you switch it off and back on, charge stored on C1 holds RESETn high. If that's a problem, a normally reverse biassed diode from C1  to V+ discharges C1 when the power fails.

Comment: yes, you're correct, I will edit the schematics, thank you

Comment: It may not be a problem ... I am just one of those very useful idiots when it comes to testing, lol! But the trick is worth knowing.

Comment: Yes, in fact the time constant is very fast (assuming a "0"-Ohm load), but I also like stressing my circuits by quickly turn on/off and see if any erratic behaviors occur. The diode will help in preventing them (provided that the circuit will have an equivalent load resistance much smaller than 100 Ohm, otherwise adding the diode might not bring significant advantages).

Comment: Yes, without the diode, it seems it turns on "again" when pressing the button, as if it is not obeying the push event for turn-off.